# MVC View Model Grab single record not a list of records, rewrite

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I realized last week that my view model is populating with a list of records when all I really want is a single record of the selected record from my view.  I've deduced that it is my view model that is wrong but I can't seem to wire my brain on how to change it so it just spits out the selected record and not a list of records from the database.

```
public class SummaryVM : BaseViewModel
{
    public IList<RecordVM> Records { get; set; }
    public SummaryVM()
    {
        this.Records = new List<RecordVM>();
    }
}
```

I am guessing I am over thinking it like I do everything.

**EDIT:** 
**New ViewModel**

```
public class SummaryVM : BaseViewModel
    {
    public RecordVM Record { get; set; }
}
```

**My Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Summary(int id)
    {
        var vm = new SummaryVM
        {
            Record = new RecordVM()
        };

        return View(vm);
    }
```

Comment: Also, This line `if (id == vm.Record.Id )` does not make sense ! the value of `vm.Record.Id` is going to be 0 (unless you have a custom get to return some int. Not sure what you are trying to do with that line !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the collection to a single instance ?

```
public class SummaryVM : BaseViewModel
{
    public RecordVM Record { get; set; }
}
```

Now you have to make sure that wherever you are using this view model,your code is updated to treat it as a single object instead of collection (*No foreach loop etc on the `Record` property*)

Note that, we do not have a constructor which initializes the Record property to a Record instance. So you need to explicitly do that before accessing any property on the record type

```
var vm= new SummaryVM { Record = new RecordVM() };
vm.RecordId = 123;
```

Do a `null` on the Record property before accessing any of it's properties to prevent the "Object Reference not set to an instance" error

```
@model SummaryVM
<h2>Record</h2>
@if(Model.Record!=null)
{
  <h3>@Model.Record.RecordI</h3>
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew I was over thinking it.  I had to rewrite my controller a bit, however now my var vm is producing a null. On Debug it says its throwing a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Where are you getting `null` ? In my answer sample, I am initializing it to `new SummaryVm { Record = new RecordVm() };`

Comment: I'll add my controller to my question

Comment: That line of code looks fine. Now, what i don't know is whether you are doing something inside the `EndPointVM` constructor. I suggest to put a breakpoint in your method and inspect the variable values to find out which one is null